# Change a specific color on a Texture2D to another color

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite

I am very new to texture manipulation so please forgive me for being too naïve on this.
I want it that when the player clicks a pixel color, it would change the all the pixels that has the same color of the clicked pixel in to the color `green`. I messed around with `Texture2D.GetPixel` and `Texture2D.SetPixel` but all I managed to do was change a specific single pixel on a very specific area:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    mColor = mTexture.GetPixel(0,0);
    mTexture.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.green);
    mTexture.Apply();
}
```

Is there a way I could change all the pixels that has the same color of the clicked pixel in to the color `green`?

Answer (score 0):

To get all the pixels of the texture, use `GetPixels`.  Once you have the array of pixels, loop through all of the pixels and compare the pixel (color) to your comparison color.  If they match, change the pixel to green.  After all modifications to the pixels array are complete, assign the pixels back to the texture using `SetPixels`.

```
Texture2D texture = myTextureReference;
Color[] pixels = texture.GetPixels(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height, 0);

for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i++)
{
    if (pixels[i] == myComparisonColor)
    {
        pixels[i] = Color.green;
    }   
}

texture.SetPixels(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height, pixels, 0);
texture.Apply();
```